# VBA Data conversion texte format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to convert datas:

```
Date;Employee;Ticket number;Table number
30/09/2016;Josh;005421;17
30/09/2016;Annie;004412;25
30/09/2016;John;001124;12
```

I need to change the format of my third column, otherwise i'll lose the "zeros".

Expected result :

[image: Expected result]

My code is the following :

```
 Range("A6:A1048576").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A6"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, Semicolon:=True, Fieldinfo:=Array(Array(3,2))
```

The problem is that the format changes on the FIRST column with my code, not the third. I don't understand why.

The problem gotta be here :

```
 Fieldinfo:=Array(Array(3,2))
```

I recorded the process with the macro editor : 
[image: Format text for col 3]

```
Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '

    '
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True
    Range("B6").Select
End Sub
```

My code looks similar to the macro editor. Therefore, I don't get why I don't get the expected result.

Could you please give me a hand?

Thanks and have a great day

Comment: It's unclear to me what your actual goal is. Can you [edit] and add how your data looks like before and should look like **after** the conversion? What do you mean by "converts the first column, and not the third."? Always add to your questions: What does your code actually do and what do you expect it to do. Always try to provide a fully working [mcve].

Comment: What happens if you record a macro doing the same thing?

Comment: @Peh hi, this is what I want : http://hpics.li/a8bcb06
Raw datas : 
Date;Employee;Ticket number;Table number
30/09/2016;Josh;005421;17
30/09/2016;Annie;004412;25
30/09/2016;John;001124;12

Comment: Code generated with the macro editor : 
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=True, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:= _
        True
    Range("B6").Select
End Sub

Comment: Please use the [edit] button to add it to your question and format it nicely. This is unreadable.

Comment: I'd like to convert the numbers in the THIRD column as TEXT so I don't lose the "00" : http://hpics.li/0d67dee. My problem is, when I use Array(Array(3,2)) with the code provided in my post, it does not work. The example I'm giving is not the real project I'm working on. It's an example to show you where I'm struggling.

Comment: @Peh, it's done. Hope it's clearer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your macro recorder shows you need to specify

```
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 2), Array(4, 1))
```

One array for each column.

> When the data is delimited, this argument is an array of two-element arrays, with each two-element array specifying the conversion options for a particular column. The first element is the column number (1-based), and the second element is one of the xlColumnDataType constants specifying how the column is parsed.

---

Here is an example how to generate an array for FieldInfo dynamically:
First we need to determine how many columns we need. We do this by counting the semicolons.

```
Sub GeneraterFieldInfoArrayExample()
    Const cDelimiter As String = ";"

    Dim str As String
    str = "30/09/2016;Josh;005421;17" 'replace with representative data, something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6").Value

    Dim countCols As Long
    countCols = Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, cDelimiter, "")) + 1 'determine how many columns are needed by counting semicolons. Afterwards we build the array.

    Dim arrFieldInfo() As Variant
    ReDim arrFieldInfo(countCols - 1) As Variant 'resize array

    Dim iCol As Long
    For iCol = 1 To countCols 'generate array for each column
        Select Case iCol
            Case 3, 10 'format column 3 and 10 as text
                arrFieldInfo(iCol - 1) = Array(iCol, 2)
            Case Else 'format any other columns as default
                arrFieldInfo(iCol - 1) = Array(iCol, 1)
        End Select
    Next iCol

    'use like: Fieldinfo:=arrFieldInfo()
End Sub
```

In the first case all columns which have to be formatted as text ar listed. All other columns become default format. You can add additional cases on your needs.

Comment: Peh, thank your for your answer. This solution "annoys" me a bit. Actually, I need to do this on a file that contains approximatly 100 columns... Is there any other solution available to make the code look a bit lighter?

Comment: Reading the [references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) it looks like `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(3, 2))` should work as well on `DataType:=xlDelimited` but somehow it doesn't. So I only see the chance to dynamically create that huge array.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later on when I'll have some time. I hope the code won't become too slow. I'll let you know how it works or if I find any other solution in the meantime. See you :)

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I've done the ugliest thing, with a huge array (163 columns haha). It works, but i'd like to do something better... I read I could do this dyncamically instead of repeating Array(1, 1), Array (2, 1) etc. Do I have to inspire myself from tutorial like this to generate a dynamic array? http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/dynamic-array.html Thxxxx !

Comment: @Jean-FIC I added an example how you would dynamically create an array for the Fieldinfo

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to read this during the w-e :) Have a great day